# Why Google Chrome scroll down to end of the page when page is refreshed?

Tags: php, jquery, google-chrome, symfony1, scroll

Why Google Chrome scroll down to end of the page when page is refreshed grammatically or by `F5` Key. It is working fine on other browsers.

I am using `php`, `Symfony` `JavaScript`, `jQuery` and some jQuery plugins on Page.

Any Idea ???

Thanks

Comment: Scrolling ? Do you have a ID Reference like example.org/home.php#test_block in your URL ?

Comment: if you use jquery you are using javascript tbh

Comment: @Johann du Toit: ohh. There is a `#` at the end of the URL. I think it is added sometime during clicking any link on the page...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't act any differently to other browsers, as far as I am aware - it will scroll to the point the page was at when it was refreshed. Does the page have a #reference after the URL (ie. http://www.url.com/index.htm#thisbit )?

Answer (score 1):

Chrome just like many browsers tries to scroll to the last position you were before hitting F5.
It should not scroll on its own but maybe something within your page confuses it, like a frame or so.
Maybe also make a complete refresh using ctrl+F5 once.

For more detailed help you should supply a live example or something similar that reproduces your issue.